# VBA: What Does acDiaglog Mean?

Tags: forms, vba

I would like to know what does this `"acDialog, x"` means? 
it is VBA code.

```
Case "btnInfo"
      DoCmd.OpenForm "Info", , , , , acDialog, "x"
```

Comment: From your comments, it seems you are missing maximize and minimize buttons. You need to check the Format tab of the form's property sheet to ensure that Min Max Buttons property is set to Both Allowed.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try that and will post the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "x" at the end is a parameter that gets sent to the form's OnLoad event and to its OpenArgs property. It's basically a parameter that helps the form initialize itself somehow (think class constructor parameters).

Comment: ok, how can I have the form with maximize and minimize button? Because now if I open the form, I only have the close button. "x" here has nothing to do with the close button?
Thanks

Comment: No, nothing to do with the close button. It's more akin to the `Tag` property from VB6. It's just an object you set to use later on. It's only for you and your code, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
OpenForm(FormName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, DataMode, WindowMode, OpenArgs)
         "Info"  ,     ,           ,               ,         , acDialog, "x"
```

The dialog is the window mode for the form being opened, so open as a dialog.
The "x" is the open args, which will set the form's OpenArgs property, which subsequent code within the form can access. But this is not like a constructor, more like setting a property of the form object.

Comment: thanks. When I tried to eliminate the "x" at the end and only have the acDialog, it works the same way as I have the "x" at the end. So I don't really see the difference.

Comment: Unless the form "Info" actually contains code that references the OpenArgs property, you won't have any difference - it would be passing a value that is just subsequently ignored.